# I want to apply borderTopRightRadius but its not working in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I want to apply borderTopRightRadius property to 23 but the View is not working with @ui-kitten.

Here is the code:

```
import {View} from 'react-native';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { Button, Layout, Text, Input } from '@ui-kitten/components';
<View style={{flex: 3,borderTopRightRadius:23}}>
        <Layout style={{paddingLeft:18, paddingRight:18}}>
          <Layout style={{ paddingTop: 23 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>EMAIL ADDRESS</Text>
            <Input style={{paddingTop: 12}} placeholder='Place your Text' />
          </Layout>
 </View>
```

Comment: it should work have u tried checking that using any ```backgroundColor``` ? If you want a border your have to add ```borderWidth: 1``` see code here https://snack.expo.io/r2D!1Xnnv

Comment: Its working. I know. But its working without <Layout>. But I have to use <Layout> because of @ui-kitten

Comment: Not familiar with layout but i can see you have not closed one ```</Layout>``` tag , can u try adding that and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: I have closed it in my code. its just a sample. I have tried that but its still not working.

Comment: i can see you have used Layout just for the sake of padding. Whats the difference between View and Layout ?

Comment: View is react-native part and Layout is part of @ui-kitten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<View style={{ flex: 3,borderTopRightRadius:23, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
```

The border radius is being implemented, its just that its being overlapped with the contents of the Layout. So, if you add "overflow: hidden" to the view styles, the view will hide anything that's spilling out from its boundaries.